# A remote linux periodically lost connection

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I have a Centos 8 Linux server, it will periodically lost network connection.

ping it's address, will fail for a while and recover automatically.Ping from my local machine or another remote server have same results, so I am sure the problem is at server side.

what can cause this ?

```
PING 172.31.114.131 (172.31.114.131) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=0.536 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=0.642 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=0.580 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=4 ttl=60 time=0.512 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=5 ttl=60 time=0.596 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=6 ttl=60 time=0.547 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=7 ttl=60 time=0.525 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=8 ttl=60 time=0.509 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=9 ttl=60 time=0.524 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=10 ttl=60 time=0.508 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=11 ttl=60 time=0.445 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=12 ttl=60 time=0.512 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=13 ttl=60 time=0.483 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=14 ttl=60 time=0.504 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=15 ttl=60 time=0.503 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=16 ttl=60 time=0.490 ms
------------- hangs ------------------------------------------
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=310 ttl=60 time=1.35 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=311 ttl=60 time=0.487 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=312 ttl=60 time=0.495 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=313 ttl=60 time=0.556 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=314 ttl=60 time=0.492 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.114.131: icmp_seq=315 ttl=60 time=0.544 ms
```

the hang/recover loop is at a fixed rate, every time icmp_seq will lost 294.

Comment: What is in system logs (e.g. `dmesg`) of the affected system? What if you set up ping inside screen (for example) and see if ping from that machine to, say, 8.8.8.8 fails too? What traceroute shows during normal operation and during failure (e.g. can you guess on which hop the problem reside)?

Comment: Are there _any_ network devices between you and your server which may decide to drop packets?